# Using wildcards in Sql to match patterns

Tags: sql, oracle11g, wildcard

im trying to match patterns in a sql using LIKE.

I have values like in P1Sign:

```
XKA,
XKB,
XSA,
XSB,
XAA, 
any other combination starting with X
```

This I like to match like this:

```
XK% = A,
XS% = B,
X[!KS]% = C, (string staring with X, where 2nd char not K or S)
```

This I put in a table called T16Kode and join it in as T16.Besk

The Sql:

```
AND P1Sign LIKE T16.Besk ('XS%')
```

and

```
AND P1Sign LIKE T16.Besk ('XK%')
```

Works fine and finds XKA,XKB and XSA,XSB
but

```
AND P1Sign LIKE T16.Besk ('X[!KS]%')
```

doesn't match XAA

When I run this I expect it to get XAA so I can match it with 'C'
Why don't I get the expected result? Cant I use [!KS]? Is there any other way I can solve this in the sql?

Here is more of the sql:

```
FROM p1perso P1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T16KODE T16 ON P1.p1adm = T16.T16Adm AND T16.T16KType = 'BHSIGN' AND P1.P1Sign LIKE T16.Besk
```

Comment: NOT LIKE 'XK%' AND NOT LIKE 'XS%'?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I edit my question to more reflect what im trying to do

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions (it only supports `_` and `%` as wildcards nothing more). You need to use `regexp_like` if you need that. Please see the manual

Comment: Simply use `SUBSTR` to check first and second character. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but I need to be able to represent my options (e.g. X% = C)  in a table so the user can edit them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of regexp_like

```
WITH DATA AS(
    SELECT 'XKA' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XKB' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XSA' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XSB' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XAA' FROM dual
    )
    SELECT str
    FROM DATA
    WHERE regexp_like (str, 'X[^KS]');



X -> first character
^[KS] -> second character not in K or S
```

Answer (score 0):

> X[!KS]% = C, (string staring with X, where 2nd char not K or S)

How about simply `SUBSTR` -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'XKA' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'XKB' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'XSA' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'XSB' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'XAA' FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT str
  9  FROM DATA
 10  WHERE SUBSTR(str, 1, 1)    = 'X'
 11  AND SUBSTR(str, 2, 1) NOT IN ('K', 'S');

STR
---
XAA

SQL>
```

where, `SUBSTR(str, 1, 1)` is to check first character and `SUBSTR(str, 2, 1)` is to check the second character.